# How can I play a sound in python using a mac?

Tags: python, macos, oserror, python-playsound

How can I play a sound in Python? I tried using `playsound` and saying `playsound('explosion.mp3')` but I get an error saying that:

```
  raise IOError('Unable to load sound named: ' + sound)
OSError: Unable to load sound named: file:///Users/Tyler/Desktop/Coding/Surround! v1.1/explosion.mp3
```

Is there a different module that works better for Mac? Or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most text editors have their own sound modules. It is completely normal for some sound modules to have no effect on the text editor you are using. Try looking up `Sound module for [text-editor]` or try finding a sound module in your text editor's built in marketplace.

Comment: Thanks! I found a module named `simpleaudio` and hopefully it works!